# updating a listfragment from an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursorloader

I am trying to update my listfragment when a button is pressed. the button puts a name into a database but how do I update the list so that name appears? the listfragment uses a cursorLoader to load from the database. I even tried using a content observer on the database and calling `getLoaderManager().restartLoader()` but that didnt work either.

So what can I do to update the list when I click a button in an activity? I have found very little information on this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure, but I assume there is something weird going on with the interaction between your `Fragment` and your `Activity`, which you are apparently displaying simultaneously somehow. Is there any reason why you are listening for the Button in the Activity? Are you dealing with a multi-pane screen or something? It seems like it'd be a lot simpler to just have the Fragment deal with this itself (since it is the one implementing the `LoaderCallbacks`, I assume).

Also, be sure that you are implementing your `Fragment` lifecycle correctly... i.e. you call `initLoader()` and set the list's adapter in `onActivityCreated()` as opposed to `onCreate()`.

Hope that helps!